# Como converter string para o tipo int em C?

Tags: c, string, conversão-de-tipo, int

Tentei utilizar o `itoa()`, mas parece que a plataforma URI não aceita, alguém poderia me dar outra forma de converter de `string` para `int`?

Aqui está o código que eu tentei

```
itoa(n1, p1, 10);
```

Comment: Tentou utilizar atoi?

Comment: não sabia que tinha essa, função preciso estudar um pouco mais

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Se sua ideia é converter string para int, deve usar **[atoi](https://fresh2refresh.com/c-programming/c-type-casting/c-atoi-function/)**:

```
char num[10] = "100";
int valor = atoi(num);
```

**detalhe:** em *C* existem funções específicas, de acordo com o tipo de dado de entrada e de saída:

- **[atof](http://fresh2refresh.com/c/c-type-casting/c-atof-function/)**() Conversão de *string* em *float*
- **[atoi](https://fresh2refresh.com/c-programming/c-type-casting/c-atoi-function/)**() Conversão de *string* to *int*
- **[atol](https://fresh2refresh.com/c-programming/c-type-casting/c-atol-function/)**() Conversão de *string* to *long*
- **[itoa](https://fresh2refresh.com/c-programming/c-type-casting/c-itoa-function/)**() Conversão de *int* to *string*
- **[ltoa](https://fresh2refresh.com/c-programming/c-type-casting/c-ltoa-function/)**() Conversão de *long* to *string*

Comment: Para C++11 existe a função `std::stoi`. Veja essa discussão (em inglês) sobre as vantagens dessa última: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20583945/what-is-the-difference-between-stdatoi-and-stdstoi

Answer (score 1):

Em geral o `atoi()` e funções assemelhadas são consideradas funções inseguras e não devem ser usadas, a não ser com verificação que a conversão funcionará, o que praticamente fará você escrever uma função complexa manualmente. Então prefira usar [`strtoul()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtoul). Ela gera um `unsigned long` que é considerado melhor para este tipo de conversão, depois se quiser pode verificar de forma simples e converter para `int` se ele for necessário.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
int main(void) {
    const char *p = "10 200000000000000000000000000000 30 -40";
    printf("Parsing '%s':\n", p);
    char *end;
    for (unsigned long i = strtoul(p, &end, 10); p != end; i = strtoul(p, &end, 10)) {
        printf("'%.*s' -> ", (int)(end-p), p);
        p = end;
        if (errno == ERANGE) {
            printf("range error, got ");
            errno = 0;
        }
        printf("%lu\n", i);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ASvJNq). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/mgivgsyhhk-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Math/StringToLong.c).