# Problema ao transformar string em int: "error: no matching function for call to stoi"

Tags: c++, string, conversão-de-tipo, int, vector

Estou escrevendo um pequeno programa que terá como *input* uma sequência de números inteiros como string e como *output* um vetor com o dobro de cada um dos números, também como string. Apesar da função `atoi` ser indicada nessa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/272801/como-converter-string-para-o-tipo-int-em-c), li [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663709/how-can-i-convert-a-stdstring-to-int) que é melhor utilizar a função `std::stoi`.

Ocorre que quando tento transformar a `string` para `int` utilizando `std::stoi`, o programa retorna o seguinte erro:

```
 error: no matching function for call to ‘stoi(__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<char> >::value_type&)’
```

Segue abaixo meu código para replicação do erro:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std; 

int main(){
    string var1="1234";
    vector <string> empty(4,"a");
    for (int i=0;i<4;i++){
        int var2=stoi(var1[i]);
        empty[i]=2*var2;
    }
    for (string x : empty){
        cout<<x<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Por que esse erro está ocorrendo e como faço para corrigir?

Comment: Você está utilizando a função `stoi` de forma errada. Tente: `std::string::size_type sz; int var2=stoi(var1, &sz);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não precisa usar essa função. O que retorna em `var1[i]` é um caractere, então nem poderia usar essa função que espera uma `string`.

Coloquei no código a forma mais simples de converter um caractere em algarismo (não fiz validação se é algarismo, até porque aí várias outras coisas precisariam ser validadas ou tornar genéricas).

E converti o resultado pra `string` já que daria outro erro em seguida por tentar guardar um número em um lugar que espera uma `string`. Nem sei se deveria ser `string` ali.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std; 

int main(){
    auto var1 = "1234";
    vector<string> empty(4, "a");
    for (auto i = 0; i < 4; i++) empty[i] = to_string(2 * (var1[i] - '0'));
    for (auto x : empty) cout << x << endl;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Sb1kQ2). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/CharToInt2cpp). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Typing/CharToInt2.cpp).

Comment: porque `var1[i]` não é `var1`, até você lendo dá pra perceber que são coisas diferentes. `var1` é `string`, `var1[i]` é um elmento de `var1` o que é um elemento de um texto? Um caractere, não é outro texto. Posto de outra forma o operador `[]` está definido no objeto para retorna um `char`.